# DT package not working with blogdown using hugo-future-imperfect theme

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo

I have a blogdown site based on the hugo-future-imperfect theme where a DT output is created correctly in the rmd but the data is not shown (although the headings are) when applying serve_site/build_site

I have created two brand new sites ( so with no other complications) to illustrate the issue.  This is the code and outputs

````
```{r DT}
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  datatable()
```
````

a) default theme
[image: defaulttheme]

b) hugo-imperfect
[image: imperfecttheme]

Comment: I've experienced the same issue using Hugo Academic. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://owi.usgs.gov/blog/leaflet/ and https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/20 the answer is to display the output in an iframe. So:

Bind the output to a variable in your code, do not display the output from this block:

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- iris %>% 
  datatable()

d1

```
````

In the next block, save the widget to a separate file (hide the code and output from this one).

````
```{r, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(d1, file = "d1.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

```
````

The widget is not saved as d1.html, instead a folder d1 is created and a file index.html is created in the folder. You need to reference this index file from an iframe tag (outside of a code block)

```
<iframe seamless src="../d1/index.html" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

You should see the output from this iframe in your page.

It's not a pretty workaround. Hopefully the problem will be solved within rblogdown soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Couple of points. I think it should be src="../d1/index.html"  Also I found combining all the code in one chunk (without the d1 line) sufficed. Any reason for splitting it? Hopefully, this issue is fixable or at least we get a list of themes and widgets that require the hack

Comment: Good spot on the typo. I've edited that out. The reason for splitting the code into different chunks is that you may not want your readers to see the chunk containing the widget save as this would not form part of the example you are presenting. I imagine this wouldn't always be the case, just an option.

Comment: So that's a bad point (groan) and a good point, then.. Thanks again very helpful

Comment: Same issue, same theme. This seems to work for the post itself but the front page of the website nows seems to self-reference and instead of there being the table there is my website again? Do you have this problem?

Comment: @mdgbeck In the end I switched to the Icarus theme. Hopefully that works for all htmlwidgets

Comment: actually, if I run `
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(d1, file = "d1.html", selfcontained = TRUE)` it does create a d1.html file. The file is created in the content/post directory of blogdown, and as a consequence it messes up with regular posts...

Answer (score 11):

You can use the package `widgetframe`.

Install the package, then save your datatable in a variable.

```
install.packages("widgetframe")

ts <- iris %>% DT::datatable()
```

So when you want to display the datatable, just do it:

```
widgetframe::frameWidget(ts)
```

That works for me!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to MrHopko's answer above you can hack datatable support into your theme. I just hacked my hugo theme to support datatables this morning.

In my example you will make the changes in theme directly, but it is possible to use the override mechanism instead.

you can run `DT::saveWidget(d1, "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)` once to generate the necessary libraries. Then copy "temp_files/*" to "themes/your-theme/static/lib"

This will copy over a few javascript libraries. Then you will need to reference them in your theme. Then you need to bring in the libraries to your partials. Then you need to copy the dependencies from "temp.html" into their associated partials.

You then need to set it so your posts load these dependencies. In my case I needed to put the `<script>` tags into "themes/my-theme/layouts/partials/scripts.html" and the `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` tags into "themes/my-theme/layouts/partials/head.html".

In my case I added:

```
<link href="{{ "lib/datatables-css-0.0.0/datatables-crosstalk.css" | relURL }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ "lib/dt-core-1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" | relURL }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ "lib/dt-core-1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.extra.css" | relURL }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ "lib/crosstalk-1.0.0/css/crosstalk.css" | relURL }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

to head.html and

```
<script src="{{ "lib/htmlwidgets-1.0/htmlwidgets.js" | relURL }}"></script>
<script src="{{ "lib/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js" | relURL }}"></script>
<script src="{{ "lib/datatables-binding-0.4/datatables.js" | relURL }}"></script>
<script src="{{ "lib/dt-core-1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" | relURL }}"></script> 
<script src="{{ "lib/crosstalk-1.0.0/js/crosstalk.min.js" | relURL }}"></script>
```

to scripts.html

After that

````
```{r, results = "asis"}
DT::datatable(d1)
```
````

Should work.

Comment: +1 You are a genius!! Notes for others: For me, I had to do `"/lib/...` rather than `"lib/...`. Also, I had to update htmlwidgets-1.0 to htmlwidgets-1.2. Lastly, I didn't have `scripts.html`, but a `js.html` file. All of this is theme dependent, so a straight copy-and-paste here won't work. Also, I got it to work locally but wasn't working on netlify and I realized that I had `lib/` in my .gitignore file, so I had to `git add ... -f`. And it works!