# Which Hugo themes support unaided htmlwidgets when using blogdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, blogdown

I'm trying to know which Hugo themes support htmlwidgets [without further tinkering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43594039/3588823). I've consulted the [latest blogdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/), the [blogdown questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blogdown) and joined the RStudio webcast in the last week to answer my question, but without success.

The reason I ask is that, at first glance, Hugo themes seem richer than bootstrap-themed Rmarkdown websites. However, having tried two of the more sophisticated themes (i.e. `Creative Portfolio` and `Tranquilpeak`), I only seem to be able to get either a sophisticated Hugo theme or a functioning htmlwidget but not both. This matters because the trial and error associated with these efforts isn't small.

For reference, the `blogdown` documentation says:

> If you theme uses the jQuery library, it is also likely that the
>   theme’s jQuery library will conflict with the jQuery library used by a
>   certain HTML widget.

I was therefore wondering: **Have any of you successfully used an htmlwidget in a Hugo theme with blogdown? If so, which theme did you use?** If you have tried and failed, an answer would still be useful, so that I can avoid that theme for now.

I realise that blogdown is still a work in progress, and am excited about where it is headed, but assumed that it would benefit many to get a sense of the themes that would currently work best with htmlwidgets.

As always, many thanks to you all for your generous assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated [the section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/html-widgets.html) in the **blogdown** book you referred to. In short, there are two ways:

1. Provide a way to suppress the theme's jQuery;
2. Or use the [**widgetframe** package](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/widgetframe) (requires [this pull request](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/widgetframe/pull/7) to be merged before it works with **blogdown**).

Comment: Many thanks, @Yihui. And not just for your answer but also for the technology in general.